# How to get how many time particular Key is present in the json and get all those values using rest-assured

Tags: rest, rest-assured

Trying to get the total number of times key "orgId" present in the below json response using rest-assured.

When I use directly `response.path("orgId") ; null` is being returned

json Response is mentioned below. What could be the solution for this?

```
{
  "code": 200,
  "message": "Successfull",
  "access_token": "2342",
  "data": [
    {
      "orgId": 131,
      "orgName": "Publish",
      "orgUrl": "http://globalthoughtz.com/",
      "orgDesc": "The much-loved premium Moto X series is now called Moto Z, and has a whole new identity based around snap-on accessories. ",
      "orgLogo": "http://miriadna.com/desctopwalls/images/max/Red-autumn-morning.jpg",
      "assignWhen": null,
      "shareUrl": null,
      "shareTitle": "Share title updated",
      "shareDesc": "A few things have changed in terms of branding and segmentation, which shows that sticking to your roots doesn't mean stagnating. hello",
      "shareImage": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/fb/5d/91/fb5d91d632ff34e4ae04393926f92bde.jpg",
      "checkTwtStatus": true
    },
    {
      "orgId": 573,
      "orgName": "Marketing",
      "orgUrl": "http://123.com/ ",
      "orgDesc": "werf",
      "orgLogo": "",
      "assignWhen": null,
      "shareUrl": null,
      "shareTitle": null,
      "shareDesc": null,
      "shareImage": null,
      "checkTwtStatus": null
    },
    {
      "orgId": 574,
      "orgName": "Customer Support",
      "orgUrl": "1.com",
      "orgDesc": "test team",
      "orgLogo": "",
      "assignWhen": null,
      "shareUrl": null,
      "shareTitle": "",
      "shareDesc": "",
      "shareImage": "",
      "checkTwtStatus": null
    },
    {
      "orgId": 575,
      "orgName": "Insurance",
      "orgUrl": "facebook.com",
      "orgDesc": "Added From IE",
      "orgLogo": "",
      "assignWhen": null,
      "shareUrl": null,
      "shareTitle": "",
      "shareDesc": "",
      "shareImage": "",
      "checkTwtStatus": null
    },
    {
      "orgId": 637,
      "orgName": "Sales",
      "orgUrl": "http://uae.souq.com/ae-en/apple/smart-watches-511/",
      "orgDesc": "CHECK CSRF ",
      "orgLogo": "http://leads.plus/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/sales-teamwork.jpg",
      "assignWhen": null,
      "shareUrl": null,
      "shareTitle": "",
      "shareDesc": "",
      "shareImage": "",
      "checkTwtStatus": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`path(String, String...)` allows you to use groovy to parse response body, so you could easily write `response.path("data.orgId.size")` and get the actual size of `data.orgId` array